# pgfplots produces stretched pictures

Tags: pgfplots

The plots produces by pgfplots seem to be slightly stretched so that right angles are not preserved.

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=full,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin {center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
  width=1\linewidth,
  axis lines=middle,
  grid,
  ymin=-10,
  ymax=10,
  ytick={-10,...,10},
  xmin=-10,
  xmax=10,
  xtick={-10,...,10},
  xlabel=x,
  ylabel=y
]
\addplot[black,mark=*] coordinates {(-3,-4) (4,1)}
node[pos=0,left] { A (-3,-4) }
node[pos=1,above right] { B (4,1) }
node[circle,draw=none,fill=none,font=\normalsize,midway,above] {\textit AB};
\addplot[black] coordinates {(-3,-4) (4,-4)}
node[draw=none,fill=none,font=\normalsize,midway,below] {\textit a};
\addplot[black] coordinates {(4,-4) (4,1)}
node[draw=none,fill=none,font=\normalsize,midway,right] {\textit b};
\addplot[black] coordinates {(4,-4) (4,-11) (-3,-11) (-3, -4) };
\addplot[black] coordinates {(4,-4) (9,-4) (9,1) (4,1) };
\addplot[black] coordinates {(-3,-4) (-8,3) (-1,8) (4,1) };\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Polot output]

Do you see the bended angles? Where do they come from?

Comment: Welcome! BTW, use math mode for typesetting axis labels and text nodes, `xlabel=$x$`, `node{$A(-3,-4)$}`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the  `axis equal image` option.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=full,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin {center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
  width=1\linewidth,
  axis lines=middle,
  grid,
  ymin=-10,
  ymax=10,
  ytick={-10,...,10},
  xmin=-10,
  xmax=10,
  xtick={-10,...,10},
  xlabel=x,
  ylabel=y,
axis equal image,
]
\addplot[black,mark=*] coordinates {(-3,-4) (4,1)}
node[pos=0,left] { A (-3,-4) }
node[pos=1,above right] { B (4,1) }
node[circle,draw=none,fill=none,font=\normalsize,midway,above] {\textit AB};
\addplot[black] coordinates {(-3,-4) (4,-4)}
node[draw=none,fill=none,font=\normalsize,midway,below] {\textit a};
\addplot[black] coordinates {(4,-4) (4,1)}
node[draw=none,fill=none,font=\normalsize,midway,right] {\textit b};
\addplot[black] coordinates {(4,-4) (4,-11) (-3,-11) (-3, -4) };
\addplot[black] coordinates {(4,-4) (9,-4) (9,1) (4,1) };
\addplot[black] coordinates {(-3,-4) (-8,3) (-1,8) (4,1) };\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```